# How to handle nested quota for pg insertion

Tags: postgresql

I have a table two info two fields:

```
create table t (
   id  serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   info jsonb
)
```

When I try to insert a row:

```
insert into t (info) values ('{"a": "b", "c": "c\"aa\"c"}'::jsonb)
```

I got an error:

```
Token "aa" is invalid.
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: whats the info::jsonb wanted value?.. what client you use?

Comment: I tried with both DBeaver and Ruby script.

Comment: do you have `standard_conforming_strings` set to off?..

Comment: How to set that? I'm new to pg.

Comment: `select name,setting from pg_settings where name= 'standard_conforming_strings' or name like '%escape%';` in dbbeaver

Comment: standard_conforming_strings off, and escape_string_warning on.

Comment: sop you have not default value. now depending on what you want to see as a result value in `info::jsonb` I can propose the actions

Comment: I want to see `c"aa"c` in result value.

Comment: but then it will not be json. json value would be `{"a": "b", "c": "c\"aa\"c"}`

Comment: Yes, in json it should be `"c\"aa\"c"`.

Comment: updated the answer - insert statement at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

cant reproduce:

```
t=# create table t (
t(#    id  serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
t(#    info jsonb
t(# );
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into t (info) values ('{"a": "b", "c": "c\"aa\"c"}'::jsonb);
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from t;
 id |            info
----+-----------------------------
  1 | {"a": "b", "c": "c\"aa\"c"}
(1 row)
```

unless I change `standard_conforming_strings` to off

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html

> `standard_conforming_strings (boolean)` This controls whether ordinary
>   string literals ('...') treat backslashes literally, as specified in
>   the SQL standard. Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.1, the default is on
>   (prior releases defaulted to off). Applications can check this
>   parameter to determine how string literals will be processed. The
>   presence of this parameter can also be taken as an indication that the
>   escape string syntax (E'...') is supported.

with backslash taken as not sting, but escape char - json structure is broken, you see it in error message:

> Token "aa" is invalid.

In order to insert valid json, you have to escape backspaces themselves:

```
t=# set standard_conforming_strings  to off;
SET
-- now when I have same settings as you:
t=# insert into t (info) values (e'{"a": "b", "c": "c\\"aa\\"c"}'::jsonb);
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from t;
 id |            info
----+-----------------------------
  5 | {"a": "b", "c": "c\"aa\"c"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hmm, `standard_conforming_strings` is about single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: Its more about backslash?.. with backslash taken as not sting, but escape char - json structure is broken, same as `e'{"a": "b", "c": "c\"aa\"c"}'` with `standard_conforming_strings ` on